# Remove virtual environment with virtualenvwrapper-win

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper

I'm trying out virtualenvwrapper-win (on Windows 7), everything works as it should, but when I try to remove virtual environments with rmvirtualenv command I am getting this output:

```
> rmvirtualenv env_py3
The directory is not empty.

Deleted C:\Users\User1\Envs\env_py3
```

And the directory (env_py3) contains just one file: pip-selfcheck.json.
How do I fix it without deleting all the directories manually?

Comment: Have you tried to manually deactivate your environment? https://github.com/davidmarble/virtualenvwrapper-win/issues/69

Comment: Yes, I run rmvirtualenv after the environment has been deactivated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a bit hacky, but you can modify the `rmvirtualenv.bat` script to include this line:

```
REM Hack to remove pip-selfcheck.json
if exist ".\pip-selfcheck.json" ( del ".\pip-selfcheck.json" )
```

I put it right after the `call folder_delete.bat` line.

Comment: It's not possible for me to check this right away, but this should work, so I'm accepting this answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply remove it as

```
rmvirtualenv <name>
```

Answer (score 1):

`rmvirtualenv` will deactivate the virtualenv for you. The problem you're describing (https://github.com/davidmarble/virtualenvwrapper-win/issues/78) has since been fixed.